# Scrolling an image within a container that's dynamically sized with the window?

Tags: html, css

I have a wide image that's wider than the typical browser window. I'd like to contain it in a scrollable `DIV` (or some other container) that scrolls independently of the main window scrolling.

I've got close with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bs8hqkj5/).

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.scroll_box {
  background-color: #586;
  color: #000;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  /* this almost works but breaks the 
         layout of the parent elements. */
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.scrollable_img {}
```

```html
<table class="wrapper" border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="scroll_box">
        <img class="scrollable_img" src="" width=2048 height=16\>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But as you can see the layout of the scrollable container is set to absolute which breaks the layout of the table that it's contained within. Also the page body padding is ignored.

[image]

So, how do I achieve this whilst..

1. Keeping relative layout so that the parents are all size correctly and body padding is observed.
2. Avoiding javascript, this needs to be embedded in a wiki system that doesn't allow javascript.
3. Dynamically resizing the scrollable container to the window size.
4. If possible the solution should be able to deal with images of unknown size.

Many thanks to anyone who can figure this out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get it right, adding a wrapper to the table with the following styles

`position: relative;` 
  `width: 100%;`

will do the job, I have edited your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zqbgv0oc/)

**EDIT**: A better attempt can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cpxqaw6k/). Additional actions:

1. Removed `position: absolute` from `.scroll_box`
2. Added the following rules at table element:

   `table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;`
3. Removed the previously added wrapper and its style because it is not needed after the above modifications, as it seems.

Comment: Almost, this fixes the page padding issue but the table is still not laid out correctly. Good attempt though!

Comment: @Kaloth Hey, thank you, I have also updated my answer.

Comment: Perfect! The edited version has everything I was looking for. Thank-you so much! :D